# Reading a specific line from a website

Tags: c#, webclient, html, streamreader

How do I read a specific line from a website?

For example, I want to read only the line "Welcome to the SimpleWeb" 
from http://www.simpleweb.org/

How do I use C# from that? I thought of using webclient, downloading the whole webpage and then using streamreader to read that specific line, but I want a more efficient process, so that I will directly read that line, without having to download the webpage.

Comment: Any process you do will involve downloading the whole webpage, then parsing the resulting output. You can't download part of a page.

Comment: you cannot directly access part of a webpage, you have to at least get html source as a stream, and search within it for what you need.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) as a way to get the page's HTML. If you have issues splitting that string to get what you want, ask a new question.

Comment: @mason Not strictly true. If you know where the string is in the page (and the web server supports it), [you can request a certain byte range](https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/). This is not a typical use-case, however.

Comment: Have a look at the HtmlAgilityPack library - makes this sort of thing really simple.  However you'll still need to retrieve the entire web page and then you can parse it in a similar fashion to parsing an XmlDocument: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Comment: @Phylogenesis The server has to support partial GETs , which it appears simpleweb does not.

Comment: @DStanley Fair enough. I would like to clarify that I don't think a partial request would be a good idea in this instance anyway (it would be a micro-optimisation that would have a completely negligible effect), but to point out for future readers that such a request *is possible* (dependent on webserver support).

Comment: @mason why? You can read a network stream until you reach some symbol (2nd \n, for example), and then just close connection without reading the rest of response.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy In most situations, that's not practical. The library is going to need an entire document to work with. I wouldn't worry about it anyways unless the page is huge. Preoptimization is the root of all evil, right?

Comment: @mason but point is that you can :)